# Setting a title for the sort column with $summary_fields

Tags: silverstripe

I want to set a column title for the sort column (in `$summary_fields`) for a `GridField`.

I can't seem to do something like:

```
static $summary_fields = array('Reorder' => 'Sort');
```

Although I can use the `$summary_fields` method to change the order of the columns, I can't use it to set a title for the sort column.

I am using the `GridFieldOrderableRows` component from the [SilverStripe Grid Field Extensions Module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions).

[image: GridField column title screenshot example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [now possible](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/pull/153). We can set the column heading by setting the `Reorder` label in the `$field_labels` variable:

```
private static $field_labels = array(
    'Reorder' => 'Sort'
);
```